# What is the best way to check for reparse point in .net (c#)?

Tags: c#, .net, ntfs, reparsepoint

My function is pretty much a standard search function... I've included it below.

In the function I have 1 line of code responsible for weeding out Repart NTFS points.

```
if (attributes.ToString().IndexOf("ReparsePoint") == -1)
```

The problem is now I am getting an error 
`Access to the path 'c:\System Volume Information' is denied.`

I debugged the code and the only attributes at run time for this directory are :

```
  System.IO.FileAttributes.Hidden 
| System.IO.FileAttributes.System 
| System.IO.FileAttributes.Directory
```

I'm executing this code on a windows 2008 server machine, any ideas what I can do to cure this failing?

```
public void DirSearch(string sDir)
{
    foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(d);
        FileAttributes  attributes = dInfo.Attributes;
        if (attributes.ToString().IndexOf("ReparsePoint") == -1)
        {
            foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(d, searchString))
            {
                //lstFilesFound.Items.Add(f);
                ListViewItem lvi;
                ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi;
                lvi = new ListViewItem();
                lvi.Text = f;
                lvi.ImageIndex = 1;
                lvi.Tag = "tag";
                lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
                lvsi.Text = "sub bugger";
                lvi.SubItems.Add(lvsi);

                lvsi = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
                lvsi.Text = d;//"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\MediaMonkey.GOLD.EDITION.v.3.0.2.1134.[Darkside].[Demonoid].[Grim.Reaper]";
                lvi.SubItems.Add(lvsi);

                listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }
            DirSearch(d);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody has permission to access System Volume Information except the SYSTEM account. So either change the permissions on the directory. Or much, much better catch the exception and go on.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for your answer - it seems I am getting some other interesting access denied error messages. I will need to fully research why. Windows 2003 never gave such issues.

Answer (score 18):

I'm not sure what the answer to the question is, but *please* change your attribute check to use proper bitwise operations!

```
if (attributes.ToString().IndexOf("ReparsePoint") == -1)
```

... is much more correctly written as ...

```
if ((attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) == 0)
```

Comment: Or, starting in .NET 4, `if (attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.ReparsePoint))`.

Comment: *HasFlag* does some nasty boxing, I'd advise against using it in general.

Comment: I guarantee that using HasFlag will not make any observable difference to the performance of your app. Unless it's a synthetic micro-benchmark.

Answer (score 0):

Once you get past permissions, and really want to test for junction points, [this class](https://www.codeproject.com/script/articles/viewdownloads.aspx?aid=15633&zep=junctionpoint.cs&rzp=%2Fkb%2Ffiles%2Fjunctionpointsnet%2F%2Fjunctionpointsnet_src.zip) provides testing for, creating and deleting of junction points through the use of DeviceIoControl kernel32 call and analysis of the reparse point.